# How to get the name of the most "root" key?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a js object in NodeJs application:

```
> req.body

{ my_root_key: { some_key2: [ [Object] ], some_key3: [ [Object] ] } }
```

How can I obtain the name of the most base key, in this case "my_root_key"?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)[0]` if it has only one, otherwise the "root" has no name from that vantage point.

Comment: `for(var it in obj){}; alert(it);` avoids creating an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = { my_root_key: { some_key2: [ [Object] ], some_key3: [ [Object] ] } }
console.log(Object.keys(data)[0]);
```